# Why am I getting this weird "Cannot set property of undefined" in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a very simple nodeunit test, exactly like this:

```
'use strict';

var controllerUtils = require('../lib/controllerUtils');

function Mock() {
    this.req = { headers: {} };
    this.res = { };
    this.nextWasCalled = false;
    this.next = function() {
        this.nextWasCalled = true;
    };
}

module.exports = {
    'acceptJson': {
        'Verify proper headers were set': function(test) {
            var mock = new Mock();
            controllerUtils.acceptJson(mock.req, mock.res, mock.next);

            test.ok(mock.nextWasCalled);
            test.equal(mock.req.headers.accept, 'application/json');
            test.equal(mock.res.lean, true);
            test.done();
        }
    }
}
```

But when I call `controllerUtils.acceptJson` I get the error `TypeError: Cannot set property 'nextWasCalled' of undefined`.

So I have tested it on chrome's console and on node command line, the test was:

```
function Mock() {
    this.req = { headers: {} };
    this.res = { };
    this.nextWasCalled = false;
    this.next = function() {
        this.nextWasCalled = true;
    };
}

var m = new Mock();
console.log(m.nextWasCalled); //logs false
m.next();
console.log(m.nextWasCalled); //logs true
```

I can't figure out why my code is not working since this is a very trivial code and it works great on both chrome's console and node command line.

PS.: Code on `controllerUtils.acceptJson`:

```
module.exports.acceptJson = function(req, res, next) {
    req.headers.accept = 'application/json';
    res.lean = true;

    next();
};
```

Comment: Have you tried settings the context of the next callback? Like so: controllerUtils.acceptJson(mock.req, mock.res, mock.next.bind(mock)); (edit) Woops, an answer was just posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`controllerUtils.acceptJson` gets as parameter a reference to a function. It has no idea in which context it should call that function, so it calls it without any context.

Your `next` method requires that the context be the object in which it was defined. There are two ways to fix your code:

Bind the function to the context when you pass it as parameter:

```
controllerUtils.acceptJson(mock.req, mock.res, mock.next.bind(mock));
```

Bind the function to the context when you define it:

```
this.next = function() {
    this.nextWasCalled = true;
}.bind(this);
```